# Filtering through Dataframe column and return different strings - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

My goal is to make a new column called 'major_sources' . This column should filter through the 'Source' column and if the source contains a string of the following then it would return the name. The reason why I'm filtering through the Source names with .contains is because some of the sources will have the string but in a different format.

```
def major_sources(source):
    if www[www['Source'].str.contains('facebook')]:
        return 'Facebook'
    elif www[www['Source'].str.contains('google')]:
        return 'Google'
    elif www[www['Source'].str.contains('yahoo')]:
        return 'Yahoo'
    elif www[www['Source'].str.contains('instagram')]:
        return 'Instagram'
    elif www[www['Source'].str.contains('pinterest')]:
        return 'Pinterest'
    else:
        return 'other'

www['major_sources'] = www['Source'].apply(major_sources)
```

When I run this code, I get `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o Check if this helps with your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution does not work, because...

```
www['Source'].str.contains('facebook')
```

...will just return a boolean for each element in the column 'Source', thus what you actually do is `if www[True]:` or `if www[False]:` with a series of `[True, True, False, ...]` values. This is why Pandas is complaining and suggests to call something like `a.all()`, which would reduce the truth values by asking "are **all** values in the iterable True?". Anyways, this would still not give your desired result.

You can directly assign a new column by just selecting an existing column and assigning the return values from some function. Remember that `.contains` is already such a function.

**All you need** is this oneliner...

```
df["major_sources"] = df["source"].str.contains("|".join(keywords))
```

...after defining some keywords:

```
keywords = ["facebook", "google", "yahoo", "instagram", "pinterest"]
```

The key here is to concatenate each keyword with `|` via `"|".join(keywords)`, which is a logical `OR` operation for `contains()`

---

Here is a short, complete example:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import cycle


numbers = list(range(50))
chars = [chr(i) for i in range(97, 97+25)]
sources = ["facebook", "google", "yahoo", "instagram", "pinterest"]
keywords = sources.copy()
sources = ["www."+s+".com" for s in sources]
sources.extend(["www."+c+".com" for c in chars])

dat = zip(numbers, cycle(chars), cycle(sources))


# original Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dat, columns=["number", "char", "source"])
print(df.head(10))

# Dataframe after adding new column 'major_sources'
print()
df["major_sources"] = df["source"].str.contains("|".join(keywords))
print(df.head(10))
```

The original Dataframe (`df.head(10)`) then is:

```
   number char             source
0       0    a   www.facebook.com
1       1    b     www.google.com
2       2    c      www.yahoo.com
3       3    d  www.instagram.com
4       4    e  www.pinterest.com
5       5    f          www.a.com
6       6    g          www.b.com
7       7    h          www.c.com
8       8    i          www.d.com
9       9    j          www.e.com
```

After adding the new column `major_sources`, this will be the result of `df.head(10)`:

```
   number char             source  major_sources
0       0    a   www.facebook.com           True
1       1    b     www.google.com           True
2       2    c      www.yahoo.com           True
3       3    d  www.instagram.com           True
4       4    e  www.pinterest.com           True
5       5    f          www.a.com          False
6       6    g          www.b.com          False
7       7    h          www.c.com          False
8       8    i          www.d.com          False
9       9    j          www.e.com          False
```

If you now want do add the concrete major source as a unique string, we just need to add another `apply()` on a new column in our Dataframe:

```
def return_major_source(x):
    for k in keywords:
        if k in x:
            return k
    else:
        return None

print()
df["major_sources_name"] = df["source"].map(return_major_source)
print(df.head(10))
```

This will results in:

```
   number char             source  major_sources major_sources_name
0       0    a   www.facebook.com           True           facebook
1       1    b     www.google.com           True             google
2       2    c      www.yahoo.com           True              yahoo
3       3    d  www.instagram.com           True          instagram
4       4    e  www.pinterest.com           True          pinterest
5       5    f          www.a.com          False               None
6       6    g          www.b.com          False               None
7       7    h          www.c.com          False               None
8       8    i          www.d.com          False               None
9       9    j          www.e.com          False               None
```

Please also remember to give a complete example. Without some example data I had to improvise with some generated data to make it look somewhat realistic. Answers are easier to grasp, if your example supplies everything need to get to the desired solution.

Answer (score 0):

[As stated in earlier comments, `Pandas` considers `truth statements` ambigious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o).

You can modify your check from `contains` to a literal check on the values, and return a result. I used a dictionary here to simplify the check a little.

```
import pandas as pd

def get_source(data):
    data = data.lower()
    sources = { 'facebook': 'Facebook',
                'google': 'Google',
                'yahoo': 'Yahoo',
                'instagram': 'Instagram',
                'pinterest': 'Pinterest',
                }

    for key, value in sources.items():
        if data.find(key) != -1: # If key name is found in row data
            return value


columns = ['Sources']
d = ['facebook hello', ' 1111 google', '23 32 instagram', '34 3324 pinterest', '4444 yahoo']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, columns = columns)


df['Major Sources'] = df['Sources'].apply(get_source)
```

The output;

```
             Sources Major Sources
0     facebook hello      Facebook
1        1111 google        Google
2    23 32 instagram     Instagram
3  34 3324 pinterest     Pinterest
4         4444 yahoo         Yahoo
```